# Reading a visual mana bar in video game

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to read and make sense of a the mana bar captured from the Marvel Contest of Champions IOS game.

Mana bar example MCOC:

[image]

So far i have tried to do various types of template matching (in the area where the bar is expected). But this approach has only been partial successful. I am getting to many false positives. Match on 3 red bars, where it should be none. Identifying orange bars as red or green. And various other problems.

What would a good approach be to:
a) determine if a mana bar is displayed in the current image. (Maybe detect the shape of the button (bigger hexagon) regardless of it's color )

b) when the mana bar is displayed - extract percentage of the 3 sub bars filled

any pointers would be appreciated

//IamB

Answer (score 2):

From the images provided I take that the "mana bar" is always a the same location on the screen. So you don't have to "detect" it. You already know where the bars are, if they are displayed.

Sample the pixels in those regions and derive the information you're interested in.

Colour, fill rate,...